# Sorting by virtual key takes very long time in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p . * , (
  SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) 
    FROM sales s
    WHERE s.affiliate !=  ''
      AND s.pid = p.pid
      AND s.saletype =  'sale' )
  ) AS popular
FROM products p
INNER JOIN members m ON m.uname = p.vendor
WHERE (m.mpid = p.pid OR p.marketavail =  'yes')
  AND p.showinmarket =  'yes'
  AND p.pname !=  ''
  AND p.pdesc !=  ''
  AND p.active =  'yes'
ORDER BY popular DESC
```

---

Here, If i use ORDER BY popular , it takes 17 seconds to load. without this ordering , query is executed in 4 seconds.
Please tell me why it is taking too much time while ordering by virtual columns?

All tables has index on required columns, so indexing is not  the issue i guess. And if i run select count(*) for single product, it is executing in milliseconds.
And one more error i saw, If i remove SELECT word (second select word in my sql), it takes 105 sec to execute.

Please tell me if i need to give any more information.

Due to such delay in sorting, i am using php instead of mysql for sorting. Please help me to make it better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you try to inner join with sales and then `GROUP BY whatever fields you're selecting from products. Avoid using select *

Comment: we are displaying products. Its in products table. And sales table contain multiple sales detail of products. New products do not contain any data in sales table so starting from products table.

Comment: Then you can do LEFT JOIN with sales AND SUM(IF (s.pid IS NULL,0,1)) instead of COUNT(*).

Comment: SUM is not needed only need to count sales for particular products. members table is inner joined with products.

Comment: if you use LEFT JOIN with sales, when it returns a row with a NULL s.pid you don't want to count it because it means that it has no sales that's why the `SUM(IF ...` it'll return a count number. I could try writing a query for you as answer but you're selecting * from product so I don't know what to GROUP BY to write query for you.

Comment: Or You can LEFT JOIN with sales and `COUNT(s.pid)` it'll only count non-NULL s.pid so the result is the same as `SUM(IF...` but still need to `GROUP BY`

Comment: will you please show me in query. Just write [table's column name] for column for group by, i will add required. Or if you need schema of any table, let me know.

Comment: see my answer and try it by replacing column names in the select and in the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this query

```
SELECT p.column1,
       p.column2,
       p.column3,
       COUNT(s.pid) as popular
FROM products p
INNER JOIN members m ON m.uname = p.vendor
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.pid = p.pid AND s.affiliate != '' AND s.saletype = 'sale'
WHERE (m.mpid = p.pid OR p.marketavail =  'yes')
  AND p.showinmarket =  'yes'
  AND p.pname !=  ''
  AND p.pdesc !=  ''
  AND p.active =  'yes'
  GROUP BY p.column1,p.column2,p.column3
ORDER BY popular DESC
```

column1,column2,column3 are just examples of columns you want, because you're select * I don't know what column names are from product. so change them to your actual column names.

edit: try this query see if it's any faster

```
SELECT p.pname, p.vendor, p.pid, 
   COUNT( s.pid ) AS popular 
   FROM products p INNER JOIN members m ON m.uname = p.vendor 
   LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT pid FROM sales
        WHERE affiliate != ''
          AND saletype = 'sale'
        )s
    ON (s.pid = p.pid) 
   WHERE ( m.mpid = p.pid OR p.marketavail = 'yes' ) 
       AND p.showinmarket = 'yes' AND p.pname != '' 
       AND p.pdesc != '' 
       AND p.active = 'yes' 
   GROUP BY p.pid, p.pname 
   ORDER BY popular DESC
```

if it runs faster you can pre-filter products too like this query and see if it runs even faster

```
SELECT p.pname, p.vendor, p.pid, 
   COUNT( s.pid ) AS popular 
   FROM (SELECT pname,vendor,pid,marketavail
         FROM products
         WHERE showinmarket = 'yes' 
           AND pname != ''  
           AND pdesc != ''
           AND active = "yes"
        )p 
   INNER JOIN members m ON m.uname = p.vendor 
   LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT pid FROM sales
        WHERE affiliate != ''
          AND saletype = 'sale'
        )s
    ON (s.pid = p.pid) 
   WHERE ( m.mpid = p.pid OR p.marketavail = 'yes' )
   GROUP BY p.pid, p.pname 
   ORDER BY popular DESC
```

Comment: ^ this seems a lot more efficient, you only take columns needed and save MySQL a lot of work.

Comment: I just filled required columns name and ran the query, it took 17.213 sec to execute. here is running query                                                                     SELECT p.pname, p.vendor, p.pid, COUNT( s.pid ) AS popular
FROM products p
INNER JOIN members m ON m.uname = p.vendor
LEFT JOIN sales s ON ( s.pid = p.pid
AND s.affiliate !=  ''
AND s.saletype =  'sale' ) 
WHERE (
m.mpid = p.pid
OR p.marketavail =  'yes'
)
AND p.showinmarket =  'yes'
AND p.pname !=  ''
AND p.pdesc !=  ''
AND p.active =  'yes'
GROUP BY p.pid, p.pname
ORDER BY popular DESC

Comment: How large are your tables?

Comment: members table ->  8,380 rows, products table-> 1,768 rows, sales table-> 76,588 rows

Comment: are s.pid,p.pid,m.uname,p.vendor all indexed?

Comment: members table indexed by-> mpid and uname , products table indexed by ->pid and vendor, sales table indexed by-> vendor and saletype

Comment: by and do you mean they're combined indexed? or individually indexed? you can run EXPLAIN SELECT ... your select statement and see if it's using the index.

Comment: which column holds this info?

Comment: not too sure which column holds the info, i just know that if it's using the index, the index_name should show up in the result. I am still beginner at EXPLAIN interpretation.

Comment: just edited my answer, try the bottom query see if it's any faster. I am trying to filter out unwanted results first. not sure if it will run faster.

Comment: if not you can try indexing the other columns too like saletype and affiliate.

Comment: oh hurry! this gave the result just in 3.2421 sec. Thank you very very much. Is it possible to describe little bit how you made equivalent query to reduce loading? Is there any other things we can improve our loading even better?

Comment: I just use the inner select from sales where we filter out sales we don't need before the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I just updated my asnwer with another query that pre-filter products as well try that one and let me know if it's even faster.